# make a loop to new <fieldset>

Tags: javascript, html, database, loops

Hi i'm looking for help.

i made a form with

this is the list

```
<form  id="msform" class="form">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Projet</li>
        <li>Nouveau</li>
        <li>Validation</li>
    </ul>

    <fieldset ></fieldset >

    <--Model-->
    <fieldset ></fieldset >
    <fieldset ></fieldset >

</form>
```

and here's my script controlling the fieldset change:

```
$(function() {

    //jQuery time
    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
    var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
    var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

    $(".next").click(function(){
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

        //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show(); 
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                left = (now * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
                next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
            }, 
            duration: 800, 
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            }, 
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

    $(".previous").click(function(){
        if(animating) return false;
        animating = true;

        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

        //de-activate current step on progressbar
        $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show(); 
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
            step: function(now, mx) {
                //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
                scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
                //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
                left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
                //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
                opacity = 1 - now;
                current_fs.css({'left': left});
                previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
            }, 
            duration: 800, 
            complete: function(){
                current_fs.hide();
                animating = false;
            }, 
            //this comes from the custom easing plugin
            easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        });
    });

});
```

what i want is making new models from the second

like this :    **Models : [model1 : {fieldset,fieldset},
               model2 : {fieldset,fieldset}]**

that's what i want, making a form where i can make multiple models inside

a picture of my form:

[image: Form]

Thank you in advance

Comment: We don't understand your question, state firstly, the problem, what you have tried, what model are you working on, loop or are you moving to the next field set or trying to create array.

Comment: the first fieldset is the form title,  the two others are inputs, check boxes and table.